# Possible to programmatically copy files from a USB drive to a user's computer?

Tags: copy, usb-drive

I am working on a solution to provide files to my vendors and was thinking that sending out USB thumb drives that would allow users to easily copy the files on the thumb drive to their computers. Of course, I want to make this as idiot-proof as possible so I would like to do it programatically. My initial thought was to make a bootable USB drive with an autorun.ini file which would, in turn, launch a batch file which would copy the files to their computer. However, after a bit of research, I have discovered that Windows 7 and later does not support autorun.

So my next thought was to maybe use Javascript or some other language to do this for me but I have not found any solutions.

Is it possible to programmatically copy files from a USB drive to a users computer? It can be user initiated, just want it to be something simple like a button they click and then a pop-up asks them where they want to save the files on their computer.

Answer (score -1):

make the batch file and instead of activating it with autorun.ini make them execute it manually or from windows+r "h:\batch.bat"